# More than 8,000 characters possible for Excel formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, formulas

I have a formula that is over 12,000 characters, and it appears the limit for excel 2010 is around 8,000. It's a lengthy "if, and" statement, with 50+ conditions. Is there a way I can override the character limit so I don't have to separate out the formula?

Comment: If your `IF` statement has gotten this long there is almost certainly going to be a more efficient way to evaluate your criteria using one of Excel's other available functions. What are you trying to achieve? We may be able to help trim things down for you using something else... `LOOKUPS`, `INDEX`, `COUNTIFS`, etc.

Comment: I'm curious to see what the formula actually is. I'd be shocked if this was the best approach.

Comment: Would you post the file with the long formula, so we can have a look at it, for sure there will be more than one way to make it more efficient.

Answer (score 5):

No, according to the [Excel specifications and limits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-ca36e2dc-1f09-4620-b726-67c00b05040f) the maximum limit of characters for a formula is is 8,192 characters. So even if you could you would likely end up with a corrupt file.

Maybe you can try break it up into parts over multiple cells, defining a macro to handle this action, or reevaluating what you are trying to accomplish.